# Kivy MDDropDownMenu callback function is not being invoked

Tags: kivy, kivymd

so the dropdown menu appears with all the choices but on clicking them the callback function is not being invoked.
What might the problem be?
Thanks in advance!
Here is main.py:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.screen = Builder.load_file('main.kv')
    channels = ['channel1', 'channel2', 'channel3', 'channel4']
    self.channels_menu = MDDropdownMenu(
        caller=self.screen.ids.add_client_screen.ids.channels_drop_item,
        items=[{"text": i} for i in channels],
        position="center",
        width_mult=4,
    )
    self.channels_menu.bind(on_release=self.menu_callback)

def menu_callback(self, instance_menu, instance_menu_item):
    print(instance_menu, instance_menu_item)

def build(self):
    return self.screen
```

And here is the .kv:

```
<AddClientScreen>:

    text: "AddClient"

    MDBoxLayout:
       orientation: "vertical"

        MDBoxLayout:
            spacing: 50
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint: 1, 0.65
        
        MDDropDownItem:
            id: channels_drop_item
            text: "Channel"
            on_release: app.channels_menu.open()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update KivyMD library from master branch. New API available only in master version (dev) - https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/master/kivymd/__init__.py#L35

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did that. After that I got the " ValueError: KivyMD: App object must be initialized before loading root widget", so I've moved the Builder.load_file() to the build method and changed the caller in the MDDropDownMenu to "self.root.ids.add_client_screen.ids.channels_drop_item". Now, I 'm getting the error "AttributeError: 'MainApp' object has no attribute 'root'". How can I fix that?

Comment: I fixed that by taking the menu out the __init__() and then calling it with Clock.schedule_once().